# Lxml in Python 2.7.6 on windows 8

Tags: python, lxml

I am getting an error of that no such module exists when I try to us the following: `from lxml import html`. 
I have downloaded the lxml-3.3.5 and installed it using 
`python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using pip?  lxml was giant pain for me to install and pip made it infinitely easier

check out this stackoverflow question for how to install

[How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

after you have installed and added in the pip keyword to command prompt

simply go:

```
pip uninstall lxml
```

to get rid of the old files

and then

```
pip install lxml
```

to reinstall